# while hiding of popover ,popover content form input fields reset automatically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Dynamically added popup form with the following code. It will act like popover content.This forms values only resetting after hide of popover.

```
   var popupform='<div class="popover-content miniform">'+
            '<form class="form" id="'+inputType+''+formIncr+'">'+
            '<div class="controls">'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Field Name </label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="fieldName" id="fieldName" >'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Label Key </label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="labelKey" id="labelKey" >'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Field Description </label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="fieldDesc" id="fieldDesc" >'+

            '<label class="control-label">Data Type</label>'+
                    '<select class="selectfield inputadjst" data-type="select" name="dataType" id="dataType">'+
                    '<option value="String">STRING</option>'+
                    '<option value="int">INTEGER</option>'+
                    '<option value="float">FLOAT</option>'+
                    '<option value="double">DOUBLE</option>'+
                    '<option value="java.util.Date">DATE</option>'+
                    '<option value="java.util.Date">DATETIME</option>'+
                    '<option value="java.util.List">LIST</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Mandatory Flag</label>'+
            '<select class="selectfield inputadjst" data-type="select" name="mandatoryFlag" id="mandatoryFlag">'+
              '<option value="Y">YES</option>'+
              '<option value="N">No</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '<label class="control-label"> ReadOnly Flag </label>'+
            '<select class="selectfield inputadjst" data-type="select" id="readOnlyFlag" name="readOnlyFlag">'+
                      '<option value="Y">YES</option>'+
                      '<option value="N">No</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Display Flag </label>'+
            '<select class="selectfield inputadjst" data-type="select" id="displayFlag" name="displayFlag">'+
                      '<option value="Y">YES</option>'+
                      '<option value="N">No</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Style Class</label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="styleClass" id="styleClass" >'+
            '<label class="control-label"> Id Field </label>'+
            '<select class="selectfield inputadjst" data-type="select" id="inputsize" name="idField" id="idField" >'+
                      '<option value="Y">YES</option>'+
                      '<option value="N">No</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '<label class="control-label">Max Length</label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="maxLen" id="maxLen" >'+        
            '<label class="control-label"> TA Rows </label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="taRows" id="taRows" >'+
            '<label class="control-label">TA Cols</label>'+
            '<input class="input-large field inputadjst" data-type="input" type="text" name="taCols" id="taCols" >'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="row" >'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="col">'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="data-sizex" >'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="data-sizey" >'+
            '<hr>'+
            '<button id="save'+inputType+''+(formIncr++)+'" onclick="getFormFields(this.id)" class="btn btn-info">Save</button><button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>'+
             '</div>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div>';      
     by clicking this list  tag only i fired popoer where data-content attribute shows i added that form dynamically.

            <li  data-content="'+popupform+'" rel="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="auto top"  data-html="true"  id="'+inputType+''+listId+'" name="'+inputType+'" data-sizey="'+datasizey+'" data-sizex="'+datasizex+'" data-row="'+datarow+'" data-col="'+datacol+'"></li>';
            this is the code for open the popover where content i added dynamically.    
            $(listValId).popover({selector: '[rel="popover"]'});

                            $(listValId).popover().on('shown.bs.popover', function(e) {

                });
```

Comment: Some code or a jsfiddle could really make a difference here :)

Comment: hi davidkonrad thanks to response me.My problem is i added form inside poppover.once i open the popover the form also open along with popover,because popover content is that form.after i filled the form text fields i force to hide,After i open the popover inside popover form text fields were cleared.so i need to prevent.how to do that pls help me out.ur valubale suggestions and solution welcome...

Comment: The `.popover-content` is injected into the DOM each time the popover is shown, therefore the forms fields are "cleared" when it popups. There is ways to go around this, but it is very hard to help without code.

Comment: <li   rel="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="auto top"  data-html="true"  id="'+inputType+''+listId+'" name="'+inputType+'" data-sizey="'+datasizey+'" data-sizex="'+datasizex+'" data-row="'+datarow+'" data-col="'+datacol+'" style="background-color: rgb(144, 144, 131); " ></li>';

Comment: davidkonard u want anything more let me know.pls give some solution.

Comment: davidkonard did u gothrough the code.Did u find anything?i am waiting for ur solution...

Comment: I am on holiday right now. Wait until saturday.

Comment: ok david.i am waiting...